# Find the closest enclosing FALSE value positions

Tags: r

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

For every TRUE value I'm looking for the positions of the closest previous and following FALSE values.

data:

```
vec <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

desired outcome: (something like)

```
     pos start end
[1,] 2   1     4  
[2,] 3   1     4  
[3,] 5   4     6
```

explanation of the **first row** of the outcome:

- pos = 2, position of the first TRUE,
- start = 1, position of the closest FALSE in front of pos = 2
- end = 4, position of the closest FALSE after pos = 2.

Already working solution:

```
pos = which(vec)
f_pos = which(!vec)

t(
sapply(pos, function(x){ s <- rev(f_pos[f_pos < x])[1]; e <- f_pos[x < f_pos][1]; return(data.frame(pos = x, start = s, end = e)) })
)
```

Comment: what if `vec` ended with `TRUE`?

Comment: good question, my solution gives back `NA`. If TRUE values are on the borders. That's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `findInterval`

```
pos <- which(vec)
b <- which(!vec)

ix <- findInterval(pos, b)
cbind(pos, from = b[ix], to = b[ix + 1])
#      pos from to
# [1,]   2    1  4
# [2,]   3    1  4
# [3,]   5    4  6
```

If we stretch your "something like" slightly, a simple `cut` will do:

```
data.frame(pos, rng = cut(pos, b))
#   pos   rng
# 1   2 (1,4]
# 2   3 (1,4]
# 3   5 (4,6]
```

---

If the vector ends with `TRUE`, the `findInterval` solution will give `NA` in 'to' column. In `cut`, the last 'interval' is then coded as `NA`.

Comment: `b[ix + 1]` very clever

Answer (score 3):

You can do as if `FALSE` defined intervals and use `data.table::foverlaps` to find the right ones:

```
library(data.table)

# put your objects in data.tables:
f_pos_inter <- data.table(start=head(f_pos, -1), end=tail(f_pos, -1))
pos_inter <- data.table(start=pos, end=pos)

# define the keys:
setkeyv(pos_inter, c("start", "end")); setkeyv(f_pos_inter, c("start", "end"))

res <- foverlaps(pos_inter, f_pos_inter)
#   start end i.start i.end
#1:     1   4       2     2
#2:     1   4       3     3
#3:     4   6       5     5
```

You can further reorder the columns and keep only the ones you need:

```
res[, i.end:=NULL]
setcolorder(res, c(3, 1, 2))
setnames(res, "i.start", "pos")
res
#   pos start end
#1:   2     1   4
#2:   3     1   4
#3:   5     4   6
```

**N.B:** this will give NA in both columns `start` and `end` if `vec` ends with `TRUE`